# Rails - How get first record of associated table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

i am trying to create an api for my mobile app.

I have `posts` and `images` tables. For my api, i can send all `posts` with:

`@posts = Post.all 
 render json: @posts`

```
Output: [{"id":20,"title":"Title 1", "body":" first post ", "user_id":1 }]
```

But it does not contain images at all. In order to show a showcase image in homepage of my app, i just need the first image of associated images.

The output which i need is (the name of `showcase_image` attribute does not matter) :

```
Output: [{"id":20, "title":"Title 1", "body":" first post ", "showcase_image": 'first_image.jpg' , "user_id":1 }]
```

I need to include first image from associated images table to my json response..

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a serializer. [Active Model Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) is pretty standard and easy to use, but is not receiving any updates and has a bad performance. You can choose any other serializer (I recommend [Blueprinter](https://github.com/procore/blueprinter)) or use the AMS.
Through the AMS you coudl define the relation you want to serialize and it would build the json you're expecting

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :body, :showcase_image, :user_id

  def showcase_image
    object.images.first.name # don't know what is the attribute you're looking for
  end
end
```

And on your controller:

```
@posts = Post.includes(:images).all # Use includes to avoid N+1 problems
render json: @posts, serialize_collection: PostSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include associations with the `:include` option when calling [`as_json`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json).

```
render json: @posts.as_json(include: :images)
```

You could limit this to one image by adding a new association to `Post`.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :images
  has_one :showcase_image, class_name: 'Image'
end
```

This would allow you to use the `:showcase_image` instead.

```
render json: @posts.as_json(include: :showcase_image)
```

---

You could also use [Jbuilder](https://rubydoc.info/gems/jbuilder/2.10.0) to solve the issue at hand without adding an additional association.

```
# app/views/posts/index.json.jbuilder

# Get images that belong to posts, group them by post_id and
# return the minimum image id for each post_id.
images = Images.where(post_id: @posts.select(:id)).group(:post_id).minimum(:id)
# Request the full image data for all image ids returned above.
images = images.keys.zip(Image.find(images.values)).to_h

json.array! @posts do |post|
  json.extract! post, :id, :title, :body, :...

  json.showcase_image do
    image = images[post.id]
    if image
      json.extract! image, :id, :name, :location, :...
    else
      json.null!
    end
  end
end
```

Without calling a specific render, Rails will default to the `app/views/posts/index` file, and select the file matching the request. (If you request HTML it will look for an HTML file, if you request JSON it looks for JSON, etc.)

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
```

Now when you request `/posts.json` or `/posts` with the header `Accept: application/json` your application should return the JSON response build by Jbuilder.